# Mysterious circle and a number appearing on my image automatically. How do I remove it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I have a circle and a number (which is "1" ) appearing on one of my images automatically. If I go "view" and uncheck "extras", they disappeared but I cannot see also guidelines which I want to show.

I think I hit some keys which I was retouching that image but I don't know what is it and how to remove it.

Comment: Can you add screenshot to your question?

Answer (score 4):

If they look similar to this....

[image]

They are color samples. They are created by using the **Color Sampler Tool** and clicking an image.

These can also be created by using the **Eyedropper Tool** and holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you click with it.

To remove them grab the **Color Sampler Tool** and <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> click them. (The cursor will change to little scissors when you hover over them with Option/Alt depressed.)

Answer (score 0):

You've accidentally turned on Slices. Slices are a web technology to break up an image into separate areas for exporting. Here's the thing you need to untick to hide it.

[image: Slices switch in View]

Answer (score -2):

On your PC, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, to turn the cursor to scissors, and then click the color sample to delete it.